# Detecting discrete touch events

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

How do I isolate touch events from each other? For example, I have one method that should be called if the view detects a single tap, and another method that should be called if the view detects a double-tap. The problem with the way I'm doing it is that a double-tap is always interpreted as a single tap before it is intereperted as a double tap. So, for example:

```m
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 if ([touch tapCount] == 1) {
NSLog(@"one touch");
 } else if ([touch tapCount] > 1) {
 NSLog(@"multi taps");
 }
}
```

If I were to single tape the screen, I would correctly log "one touch". However, if I double tape the screen, I would get to logged statements, first "one touch" followed immediately by "multi taps".

I'm sure this is simple, but could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3578-tap-double-tap.html

You use a switch and then cancel pending requests, ie:

```m
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTapMethod) object:nil];
```